# Detectar que tecla se presiona al estar sobre un elemento (mapa)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando con mapas en mi proyecto de `Django`. El problema es que cómo este ocupa gran parte de la pantalla, cuando quiero hacer scroll para moverme arriba o abajo, el cursor suele estar sobre el mapa y por lo tanto lo que modifico es el zoom.

Por lo tanto mi idea es implementar que para hacer zoom sea necesario estar sobre el mapa pero además estar pulsando la tecla `ctrl`.

He hecho este script en `js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#issMap").hover(function(){
        alert('Buenas');
        var codigo = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if(codigo === 17){
            alert('HOLA');
          }
        alert(codigo);
    });
});
```

La cosa es que al estar sobre el mapa me sale el mensaje "Buenas", así que eso genial. Pero no me detecta la tecla que presiono (17 = tecla ctrl). `codigo` siempre me sale con valor `undefined`.

¿En que me equivoco? Según otros posts veo que siempre se usa `which` o `keyCode` pero no me va bien.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Google map ya posee esa funcionalidad se realiza con `gestureHandling: 'cooperative'` la configuración completa esta en la documentación te dejo el link por si quieres ejecutar un ejemplo completo https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction

Comment: no uso maps, uso leaflet pero gracias

Comment: Haberlo dicho antes mira esta es una libreria que busca realizar el mismo efecto de presionar ctrl con leaflet https://github.com/elmarquis/Leaflet.GestureHandling y este es el ejemplo https://elmarquis.github.io/Leaflet.GestureHandling/examples/

Comment: @NEA He visto que por lo que escribís en los comentarios no es un container normal y corriente... La respuesta que he escrito era pensando en un div "normal" ... ¿Me puedes comentar si funcionaria en tu caso?, de no ser así borrare la respuesta.

Comment: Disculpad la tardanza, @RobertoEMoran había visto esto pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar, por eso intente montar el mío propio. En teoría me carga bien el `js` pero luego me dice que no lo encontraba...

Comment: @x3k_js efectivamente hablo de ese container, si la quieres borrar bórrala pero no me parece mala la respuesta. Realmente contesta a mi pregunta, la acabo de implementar y me reconoce la tecla al estar encima. Lo que si que es cierto que en mi caso no es lo más óptimo.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que el evento `hover` no es un evento con la propiedad `keyCode`, por lo que `codigo` será siempre undefined.

Entonces esto se puede arreglar de la siguiente manera:

**On, bind y namespaces**

Vamos a concatenar eventos con **[.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)** uno para cuando entra en tu div (`mouseover`) y otro para cuando sale (`mouseout`).

¿Para que **[.bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)**? 
Para poder bindear y desbindear otro evento (el `keydown`) a tu contenedor. Así tendremos el evento `keydown` solo mientras está en el evento `mouseover` que es lo que quieres.

**NOTA:** Se ha cambiado el `bind/unbind` del evento `keydown` por `on/off` ya que `bind/unbind` son métodos deprecados. La idea es la misma, quitar/desactivar/desbindear el evento cuando ya no este en `mouseover`.

El **[namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)** es como un "nick" que le ponemos al evento para saber que nos referimos a el en concreto, y así no desbindear otros eventos del mismo tipo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#issMap").on("mouseover",function(){
        $(document).on("keydown.customEvnt",function(e) {
            var codigo = event.which || event.keyCode;
            if(codigo === 17){
                console.log("On key with hover");
            }
        });
    }).on("mouseout",function(){
        $(document).off("keydown.customEvnt");
    });
});

$(document).on("keydown",function(){
  console.log("Otro key event que no queremos que se desbindee");
});
```

```css
#issMap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="issMap">

</div>
```